# 'Feeding' a Netty 4 pipeline without a socket

Tags: linux, java-stream, netty, socketchannel

I have a set of Netty 4 handlers that I normally chain on top of a `ServerBootstrap` using `EpollEventLoopGroup`s. However the source of the data will not be a socket; instead I will read from / write to two in-memory buffers. Solution can be Linux-specific.

For now I add a `ServerBootstrap` to listen to a loopback port, to which I connect with a server and manually feed the data; but I wonder if I can do this without having to use a socket at all.

I considered writing a custom `SocketChannel` that extends `LocalChannel` but there are lot of details to consider and I feel out of my depth, honestly.

I have found this repository but it is for Netty 3, not 4:
https://github.com/itm/netty-iostream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use `EmbeddedChannel`.